# IFF, THEN Expression for text color in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am doing some expression for STATUS and DATE OF THE SHIPMENT in SSRS. I wanted to make if STATUS = "IN PROGRESS", the DATE OF THE SHIPMENT will change to RED.

Both of the STATUS and DATE OF THE SHIPMENT are in different column in SSRS.
Below is the result that I wanted:

[image]

Currently, I am writing the expression inside DATE OF THE SHIPMENT textbox.
Here is the code

```
=IIF(Fields!Shipment_Status.Value ="IN PROGRESS", "Black", "Red")
```

After preview, seems like it not working.
I really need the help on this. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Your logic is backwards, you want `=IIF(Fields!Shipment_Status.Value = "IN PROGRESS", "Red", "Black")`. And the expression belongs in the "Color" property of the textbox.

Comment: @dalek, I already change the logic but the text still not change to red. Is it correct to placed the expression in the textbox of DATE OF THE SHIPMENT ?

Comment: And did you add it to the "Color" property?

Comment: @dalek, yes i added in the expression to the "Color" property.

Comment: Check the color expression in the placeholder property in the textbox as well.

Comment: also make sure that the Shipment_Status field does not contain any trailing spaces or non-printable characters, otherwise the iff condition will not return true